# issue on two multiple dropdown

Tags: php, jquery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O2Ug.png

when i change course name first row change only that row parent topic
how to do this please give advice

first course name select box code

```
<select class="form-control select2"  onChange="getval(this.value)"; id="course_id1" name="course_id[]" data-live-search="true" >
                            <option value="" selected="selected"> Select Course Name</option>
                                <?php
                                            $sql = "SELECT * from course_master";
                                            $result = $connect->query($sql); 
                                             while($row_pt = $result->fetch_array()) 
                                                 { 

                                                     ?>
                                              <option value="<?php echo $row_pt['course_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row_pt['course_name']; ?></option>

                                            <?php 
                                                 }
                                 ?>
                     </select >
```

second select box when i select course name from drop down change that row parent id

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="parent_id" name="parent_id[]" data-live-search="true" ></select>
```

call function on change in course name

```
function getval(val)
        {


                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get.php",
                data: {parent_id:val,syllabus_id:syllabus_id},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#parent_id").html(data);

                }
            });
        }
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
    include('connection/core.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['userId']))
     {
        if (!empty($_POST["parent_id"])) 
        {
            $query_sql = "SELECT syllabus_id,topic_name FROM syllabus WHERE syllabus_id!='". $_POST["syllabus_id"]."' AND course_id ='" .$_POST["parent_id"] ."'";
            $results = $connect->query($query_sql);

            echo $query_sql;
            ?>
            <option value="0" selected> Parent </option>
        <?php
            foreach ($results as $p) 
            {
            ?> 
        <option value="<?php echo $p["syllabus_id"];  ?>"><?php echo $p["topic_name"]; ?></option>

            <?php
            }
        }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the issue here? Is the value in the getVal function incorrect? Is the data you get back from the ajax incorrect? To me, it's not really clear what's wrong and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I didn't see select box with id `parent_id`. also you have dynamic dropdown that will added on click on `add row` button. Dynamically added dropdown also need this same functionality to be work right?

Comment: check image  and this code for one relationship i have clone by adding button user add many clone that have many relationship create by cloning

Comment: yogendrasinh right

Comment: how to do please give advice or give code

Comment: @tejas show your get.php file code.

Comment: yes i show you on top

Comment: get.php added with above code please give answer on it thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below code for your first row.
For example.

```
<select class="form-control select2 selectCourse" data-id="1" id="course_id_1" name="course_id_1[]" data-live-search="true" >
```

And for your parent topic name add as below.

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="parent_id_1" name="parent_id_1[]" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

Now when you are adding new dynamic row in your HTML then add `selectCourse` as class name in your `select box` of `course name` AND `data-id="1"` for each dynamically added row.

For example.
For `course name` add as below.

```
<select class="form-control select2 selectCourse" data-id="2" id="course_id_2" name="course_id_2[]" data-live-search="true" >
```

For `parent topic name` add as below.

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="parent_id_2" name="parent_id_2[]" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

**In your script add code as below.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '.selectCourse', function(){
        var course_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();

        var syllabus_id = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get.php",
            data: {parent_id:val,syllabus_id:syllabus_id},
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#parent_id_" + course_id).html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @tejas If this answer helps you then do upvote and accept it as your answer.